# Gtk TextView - place or move cursor to the text end?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk

I have a TextView widget, and I'm inserting text with insert at cursor method. My TextView Widget is editable (It must be so).
How to ensure that cursor is at the end of text in TextView before inserting a new piece of text?
I work with C#/Mono.

I know that properties like place(TextIter) exist, but i do not know, how to use this ...

Answer (score 2):

To change the position of the cursor, call `textView.Buffer.PlaceCursor(textView.Buffer.EndIter)`.

To insert text at the end programatically without changing the cursor position, call `textView.Buffer.Insert(textView.Buffer.EndIter, textToInsert)`.

Answer (score 1):

By now, the Insert() method used above is marked as deprecated, but it's easy, just use this instead:

```
textView.Buffer.Insert(ref textView.Buffer.EndIter, textToInsert)
```